# Using NetBeans on Apple MacBook Air

Tags: macbook, php, battery, netbeans

I have just purchased an Apple MacBook Air (2010 Model Top Spec, 4GB RAM, 2.13 GHz CPU, 256 GB SSD) for its extreme portability. I have been using the trial version of Coda but it seems to lack some of the functionality that is provided by NetBeans.

So I have installed NetBeans PHP and am somewhat impressed, but it seems to use a lot more battery power than Coda.

Is it possible to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Netbeans is java based, there is not much chance of improving performance to much of a degree. running on my Xeon-powered Mac Pro with 12GB of RAM it routinely will burn over a gig of memory and CPU to match. You may try modifying your workflow to accomdate your desire to work for long hours untethered, using native (optimized) code like Coda or Espresso, or VNCing to a remote machine on AC power running your Dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [coolbook](http://coolbook.se). It's a small utility that lowers the voltage on your CPU, and it is specifically for Mac portables. I've been using it on all my portables for several years now, and find it extends my battery life by about 20% without affecting performance (no kidding).

FWIW, I am also currently using the latest MBA, fully loaded, and regularly run Zend Studio and Netbeans, and also keep multiple CPU-cycle gobbling browsers open at the same time.